# Extract php filename with phing

Tags: php, joomla, aptana, phing

I'm using Aptana with Phing 3 and I am very well.
I created a build.xml script that changes some data in a php file

I have a header like this in the original file

```
/**
 / @package x--exttype--x x--complete_name--x for Joomla! x--Jversion--x
 / @version x--version--x: x--filename--x 
 / @author x--author--x
 / @link x--website--x
 / @copyright (C) x--year--x
 / @license x--license--x
**/
```

and I'm going to replace all the placeholder x--placeholder--x
everything works, except for the x--filename--x, I would take the name of the php file that contains it and put in place of. I searched the web but found nothing.

Phing has a function in the favor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, phing has a way to modify files: `ReflexiveTask`.

Example from the [manual](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/):

```
<reflexive>
  <fileset dir=".">
    <include pattern="*.html">
  </fileset>
  <filterchain>
    <replaceregexp>
      <regexp pattern="\r\n" replace="\n"/>
    </replaceregexp>
  </filterchain>
</reflexive>
```